# Use while loop instead of Cursor in the following code

Tags: sql, while-loop, cursor, sql-server-2012

Below you will see a cursor written to count how many rows there are in each table of AdventureWorks2012. Now, I am trying to use WHILE LOOP to get the same results. But, I am having trouble, can anyone help me.

```
DECLARE @table sysname
DECLARE @SCHEMA SYSNAME
DECLARE @COUNT INT
DECLARE @STR VARCHAR(200)

CREATE TABLE #REC(COUNT INT)
CREATE TABLE #REC1(SCHEMA_NAME VARCHAR(100),TABLE_NAME VARCHAR(100), COUNT INT)

DECLARE TableCursor CURSOR LOCAL FAST_FORWARD FOR 

SELECT table_schema, table_name
FROM AdventureWorks2012.[INFORMATION_SCHEMA].[TABLES]
WHERE TABLE_TYPE ='BASE TABLE'
ORDER BY table_schema

OPEN TableCursor FETCH NEXT FROM TableCursor INTO @SCHEMA, @table;

WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS = 0) 
  BEGIN
    SET @STR='SELECT COUNT (*) FROM AdventureWorks2012.'+@SCHEMA+'.'+@table;

    INSERT INTO #REC
    EXEC(@STR)

    SELECT @COUNT=COUNT FROM #REC
    PRINT @COUNT

    INSERT INTO #REC1 VALUES(@SCHEMA,@table,@COUNT)

    FETCH  NEXT FROM TableCursor INTO @SCHEMA, @table;
END 

CLOSE TableCursor; 
DEALLOCATE TableCursor; 

SELECT * FROM #REC1

DROP TABLE #REC
DROP TABLE #REC1
```

---

Help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Try running following script, to retrieve all tables from your database and number of rows each table has.

```
USE AdventureWorks2012

SELECT sc.name +'.'+ ta.name TableName
,SUM(pa.rows) RowCnt
FROM sys.tables ta
INNER JOIN sys.partitions pa
ON pa.OBJECT_ID = ta.OBJECT_ID
INNER JOIN sys.schemas sc
ON ta.schema_id = sc.schema_id
WHERE ta.is_ms_shipped = 0 AND pa.index_id IN (1,0)
GROUP BY sc.name,ta.name
ORDER BY SUM(pa.rows) DESC
```

### Hope this answers your query.

```
DECLARE @tableName1 sysname

DECLARE @SCHEMANAME1 SYSNAME

DECLARE @COUNT1 INT

DECLARE @STR1 VARCHAR(200)

CREATE TABLE #Wltable(COUNT INT)

CREATE TABLE #Wltable1(SCHEMA_NAME VARCHAR(100),TABLE_NAME VARCHAR(100), COUNT INT)

INSERT INTO #Wltable
SELECT table_schema, table_name

FROM AdventureWorks2012.[INFORMATION_SCHEMA].[TABLES]

WHERE TABLE_TYPE ='BASE TABLE'

ORDER BY table_schema

WHILE (SELECT @SCHEMANAME1=SCHEMA_NAME, @tablename1=Table_Name FROM #Wltable1)
BEGIN

    SELECT COUNT (*) FROM AdventureWorks2012.+@SCHEMANAME1+@tableName1;

    SET @STR1=@str1+1

END
```

This is where I currently stand, can't seem to get this to work.

I have updated my script, now it will return same resultset as your cursor query does.

```
SELECT  sc.name AS [SCHEMA_NAME], ta.name AS [TABLE_NAME]
,SUM(pa.rows) AS [COUNT]
FROM sys.tables ta
INNER JOIN sys.partitions pa
ON pa.OBJECT_ID = ta.OBJECT_ID
INNER JOIN sys.schemas sc
ON ta.schema_id = sc.schema_id
WHERE ta.is_ms_shipped = 0 AND pa.index_id IN (1,0)
GROUP BY sc.name,ta.name
ORDER BY SUM(pa.rows) DESC
```

Comment: can you do this using a while loop?

Comment: I think its better to store this result in some temporary table and use it, instead of using while loop.

Comment: I do have two temp tables creates #Wltable and #Wltable1 for displaying my final result

Comment: what is your requirement. what do you wish to do with the result from tablenames and its rowcount.

Comment: I want to get the same results as I did while using cursors, but use while loop this time. Is that possible?

Comment: You should only user cursors and while loops when necessary, and it doesn't seem necessary in the context of OP.